# Hiding hyperlink button for already selected tab in WEB Application

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my web application, I have tabs and if any of the tab is clicked, the corresponding page will be displayed. But even after the tab is selected, the hyperlink button is enabled. My need is that if i do mouse over on the selected tab, the normal pointer should display instead of hyperlink. please help me suggesting the solution.

regards,
Jeya

Answer (score 1):

Either

```
<a>you can't click me</a>
```

or

```
<a href='...' style='cursor:default'>you can click me but the cusror doesn't indicate this</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but I need hyperlink to be displayed until the tab is selected. Once the tab got selected, then it should changed to normal mouse pointer. Do you have any idea

Comment: If you need this to be dynamic without reloading the page, then opt for any of the JavaScript-based options below.

Comment: How to identify that the tab is selected?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete sample :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            a:target
            {
                cursor: default;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a id="anchor1" href="#anchor1">Anchor1</a>
        <a id="anchor2" href="#anchor2">Anchor2</a>
        <a id="anchor3" href="#anchor3">Anchor3</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

When you click any of the link it'll become the current target of the page, then the **a:target** rule will be applied to it, setting the default cursor.

**EDIT for IE** :

Changing my original sample, here is another implementation using **jQuery**, **tested with IE8 but not IE7**.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function()
            {
                var hash = null;

                var updateAnchors = function()
                {
                    hash = window.location.hash;

                    $(".tab").removeClass("target");

                    $(".tab[href=" + hash + "]").addClass("target");
                };

                window.setInterval(function ()
                {
                    if (window.location.hash != hash)
                    {
                        updateAnchors();
                    }
                }, 100);

                updateAnchors();
            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .target
            {
                cursor: default;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a id="anchor1" href="#anchor1" class="tab">Anchor1</a>
        <a id="anchor2" href="#anchor2" class="tab">Anchor2</a>
        <a id="anchor3" href="#anchor3" class="tab">Anchor3</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: :target is unsupported by <= IE8 :( http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t316

Comment: You're right, the above sample is only for modern browsers. +1

Comment: Thanks Serious, its working fine in Mozilla and how can we achieve this in >=IE7

Comment: You might not be able to obtain this effect in IE before IE9 without using some javascript. Here is one possible implementation : http://tests.novemberborn.net/javascript/emulate-css-pseudo-class-target-in-ie.html

Answer (score 0):

You can select an element using javascript:

`document.getElementById('element-id');`

Once you've done that, you can modify the style within that element:

`document.getElementById('your-element').style.cursor = 'default';`

Now your cursor should look normal.

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("myATagId").style.cursor = "default";
```